# Push Notification After Multiple Text Messages Android

Tags: android, notifications, android-activity, sms, push-notification

I want to have a push notification display in the status bar after the user receives 3 text messages. I then want to start a new activity after that notification is clicked. I have been searching around and haven't found any help with setting up this condition for sending out a push notification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use a Service.

You would first use an **AlarmManager** to start your Service on a set schedule (say every half hour). Your Service would then perform the logic necessary to check if a word needs a review and show a notification as appropriate.

A basic service that performs this functionality would look something like this:

```
public class ReviewCheckService extends IntentService {

 public ReviewCheckService() {}

 @Override
 protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (isNeedReview()) {
        showNotification();
    }
}
}
```

for reading about Service you can see [this site](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)

Answer (score 0):

To know how to implement Android Notification [visit this site for tutorials](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidNotifications/article.html)